# Solve Differential Equation $y'=k(1-y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I solve this equation in this way:

$y'[x] = k(1-y[x]) \rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=k(1-y) \rightarrow \frac{dy}{1-y}=kdx$

so applying integration at both sides

$\int \frac{dy}{1-y}= \int kdx \rightarrow -ln|1-y| = kx + c$

$ln|1-y| = -kx - c$

using e

$e^{ln|1-y|} = e^{-kx - c} \rightarrow 1-y=e^{-kx}e^{-c} $

solving for y

$y=1-e^{-kx}e^{-c} $ as $e^{-c}$ is constant I supposed is a negative constant so: $e^{-c} = -c$

$y=1-e^{-kx}(-C)$

> $ y=1+Ce^{-kx}$ this is my answer but the book gives me another one
>
> $ y=1-Ce^{-kx}$ this is the book's answer
>
> I would like to know which one is right

Comment: The two solutions are the same, up to the sign of C.

Comment: It's the same. (-C) can be renamed as it is just another constant.

Comment: so the sigh in C doesn't matter? because is a constant right?

Comment: There is no such thing as sign of C. What is C, really? Any number. Then what is -C? Any number.

Comment: Why would you assume that $e^{-c}$ is negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, $C$ is an *arbitrary* constant, so it doesn't really have a sign.  But in your 7th line, you drop the absolute value around $1-y$.  Your equation should read $|1-y| = e^{-kx}e^{-c}.$  If you write $e^{c}=C$, at this point we know $C$ is positive.  But when we remove the absolute value, we have $1-y = \pm e^{-kx}e^{-c} = \pm Ce^{-kx}.$   The $C$ "absorbs" the $\pm$.

It takes some time to get the hang of dealing with arbitrary constants in DE.  5 times an arbitrary constant is an arbitrary constant.  So $5C=C$.  And $4C^2+7 = C.$  And $\pm C = C$.  The rule is "Arbitrary constants absorb constants, but NOT variables."

Comment: Thanks so much, it was hard at the beginning to understand